For loops get skipped during runtime
I am trying to make a program that finds the sum of all numbers not divisible by 17 between two given integers but my for loops keep getting skipped and not executed. As a result, the variable "sum" always prints 0 to the terminal.
This is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a, b, sub, lower, j, sum;
int arr[100];

int main(){
    system("cls");

    // get numbers
    printf("Input the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Input the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    // calculate
    if (a-b > 0)
    {
        lower = b;
        sub = a-b;

        for (int i = b; i < sub; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 != 0)
            {
                arr[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (b-a > 0)
    {
        lower = a;
        sub = b-a;

        for (int i = a; i < sub; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 != 0)
            {
                arr[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    // sum
    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
    {
        sum = arr[i] + arr[i+1];
    }
    
    // result
    printf("result: %d", sum);

    return 0;
}

I have checked if the other part of the code works and it does. However, I still cannot find out why this is happening. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

See: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?.

First of all, inside for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++), you over-count and thus, over-sum. For instance, check out index i = 0 which gives you sum=arr[0]+arr[1] and then index i=1 with sum = arr[1]+arr[2]. Besides it has to be sum += arr[i]+arr[i+1]

And also, you don't have to store all the numbers and then sum them at the end. You could just add up each number as you find them.

Your loop bounds don't make sense.  For example, suppose a < b.  Then in the loop, i should run from a through b, so you want for (int i = a; i <= b; i++).  But instead you have for (int i = a; i < b-a; i++),  This loop may not run at all.  Suppose a is 100 and b is 110.  Then b-a is 10.  So the loop starts at 100 and immediately exits.  Stop trying to subtract a from b.  Just use a and b as the bounds.  You only need to subtract to create a relative index, which you're handling manually with j.

Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

Wrong loop conditions
Your conditions for the loops are incorrect. In a typical loop, it's usually done as for (int i = 0; i < cond; i++). However, you have confused your loop conditions.
Loop Logic
You have done lower to be the small of the 2 numbers and sub to be the difference between a and b. You want your for loop to repeat for sub times, but you had incorrectly implemented it. Your loops do not run sub times.
Example
Let a=8 and b=5. In  this case of a-b > 0, lower=5 and sub=3.
When you do for (int i = b; i < sub; i++), the iterations are:

i=5, 5<2 is false, loop terminates

Obviously, the above example numbers does not make much sense for your use case, but it clearly highlights the issue with the loop logic. While you had expected the loop to run three times, it ran only once instead.
Fix 1
I see that the logic instead the for loops are the same for both a-b > 0 and b-a > 0. Hence, I recommend combining them (DRY principle).
First, you check the for the higher/lower number:
if (a - b > 0)
{
    lower = b;
    sub = a - b;
}
else if (b - a > 0)
{
    lower = a;
    sub = b - a;
}

Then you implement the loop using lower and sub.
While there are a few way to make it run sub times, since you want to "collect" the value of i, you should do make the loop go from the lower number to the higher number. Hence, instead of sub, what you actually need is higher.
for (int i = lower; i < higher; i++)
{
    if (i % 17 != 0)
    {
        arr[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
}

Summing the results
As pointed out by Iman Abdollahzadeh in the comments, you "over-count and thus, over-sum". More critically,  you are NOT really adding up the values as you loop through.
Fix 2a: bound the loop correctly
Since your j actually tracks the used portion of arr, you can use it to not over count.
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    // adding logic
}

Fix 2b: adding values correctly
When you do sum = arr[i] + arr[i+1], you are adding 2 consecutive numbers and assigning to sum. However, this sum is not otherwise being used in future iterations of the loops.
To sum the values of arr together, you should do sum = sum + arr[i], or more simply sum += arr[i].
Fix 2 (Combined)
Putting fix 2a and 2b together, you get
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    sum += arr[i]
}

Summary
Your program have various bug and hence need a few fixes as I have indicated (Fix 1 and 2). Of course, you can decided to forgo the separate looping, and just add up each number as you find them (suggested by BoP in the comments).
There may also be other bugs not discovered which you should attempt to debug.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
There are a couple reasons your code isn't working which I'll explain below, but first I would recommend looking into debuggers. Debuggers are a great way to figure out where/why your code is going wrong so that you don't spend hours combing through it to no avail. As another user mentioned you can use this link to learn more.
OK, onto what's going wrong with your code. For starters, in both of your for loops you initialize i equal to the higher of the two numbers you've been given, be it a or b. This is fine, especially if you're trying to count through the integers between a and b. However, when you set the end value for the for loop (when it will stop), you set it to sub which you've calculated to be the difference between a and b. The loop is starting at the lowest of either a or b and going through each number until it hits the difference between a and b, not the higher of the two numbers. If you want to cycle through all the numbers between a and b, you could instead set the end value for the loop to the higher of the two variables, the code for the loops would be as follows:
    if (a-b > 0)
    {
        for (int i = b; i < a; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 = 0)
            {
                arr[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (b-a > 0)
    {
        for (int i = a; i < b; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 = 0)
            {
                arr[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

In these two examples you can see where I replaced sum with a and b, I also removed the unnecessary declaration of 'lower' numbers, since you've already established which case each loop is for, however if you need the variable for something else feel free to put it back in.
Another issue with the code is the use of arrays to place each digit divisible by 17. This can work to store the numbers sure, but unless you have a reason to store each number, you could save a lot of memory by just summing the numbers within the for loop, like this:
    if (a-b > 0)
    {
        for (int i = b; i < a; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (b-a > 0)
    {
        for (int i = a; i < b; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }

You'll also notice that I changed your if statements to == rather than !=. This is because when you're checking if (i % 17 != 0), you're checking for every number that does have a remainder when divided by 17. That ends up being every number other than 17. The expression you need instead is ==.
I won't go into too much detail on the for loop used to calculate the sum, since as I mentioned it's far more efficient time and memory wise to calculate it in the previous for loops, but if you insist on keeping the array system, you want to only be adding array[i] to sum once, array[i+1] will be added on the next sequence of the for loop anyway, the system you currently have is doubling numbers.
Other than that there are a few minor QOL changes I made to the code that I've written below, as well as a final version that should work for you. Definitely look into a debugger for the future, and good luck in your future coding endeavors!
QOL changes:

Added \n at the end of the printf statement to add another line after printing the sum.
removed unnecessary variables such as sub and lower
added a very basic response for invalid inputs.

Working code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a, b, j, sum;

int main(){

    // get numbers
    printf("Input the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Input the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    // calculate
    if (a-b > 0)
    {
        for (int i = b; i < a; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (b-a > 0)
    {
        for (int i = a; i < b; i++)
        {
            if (i % 17 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input, stopping program.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // result
    printf("result: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}

